# Highlight lines longer that 80 characters in vim in multiple tabs of the same file

Tags: vim, tabs, character, limit, highlight

From these two questions:

[Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns)

[Vim syntax coloring: How do I highlight long lines only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395114/vim-syntax-coloring-how-do-i-highlight-long-lines-only/10993757#10993757)

I've extracted the following config for my .vimrc:

```
augroup vimrc_autocmds
 autocmd BufEnter * highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=whitee guibg=#FFD9D9
 autocmd BufEnter * match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
augroup END
```

This works fine for highlighting lines longer that 80 characters in vim,
but when I open another tab of the same file using:

```
:tab split
```

the highlighting doesn't work in the new tab, only in the original one. How can I achieve the same effect for the new tab?

Comment: You can use another command like TabEnter similar to BufEnter. It will work

Comment: I'd just like to point out the we have a [website section specialised in vim questions](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @grochmal Didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your snippet:

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=white guibg=#FFD9D9

augroup vimrc_autocmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,WinEnter * call matchadd('OverLength', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
augroup END
```

- The autocommands in that group are properly cleared when/if you reload your `vimrc`.
- The `BufEnter` event is only triggered once, you need to listen to another event, `WinEnter`, which is triggered when a window gets the focus.
- `matchadd()` is more flexible than `:match` and allows you to set the priority of the highlighting (useful if you rely on `hlsearch`).