# How to show vertical line to wrap the line in Vim?

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I'm interested in finding a way to show a vertical line at column 80 in Vim (not GVim).

I've used `set wrap`, but I just want to show a vertical line so I can wrap the long line myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim 80 column layout concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit: For Vim >=7.3 see answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787678/1432801).

Unfortunately vim has no mechanism to display a vertical line after a column like you want (unlike, say, TextMate). However, there are alternative visual indicators that you can use to show that a line is too long.

Here's what I use (you can put this in your `.vimrc`):

```
nnoremap <Leader>H :call<SID>LongLineHLToggle()<cr>
hi OverLength ctermbg=none cterm=none
match OverLength /\%>80v/
fun! s:LongLineHLToggle()
 if !exists('w:longlinehl')
  let w:longlinehl = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '.\%>80v', 0)
  echo "Long lines highlighted"
 else
  call matchdelete(w:longlinehl)
  unl w:longlinehl
  echo "Long lines unhighlighted"
 endif
endfunction
```

So then you can use `<Leader>H` to toggle columns over 80 being highlighted.

Comment: The vim script representation of the leader key. See [Show current <leader> key setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389205/show-current-leader-key-setting)

Comment: @Will, [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) is a good resource to learn about the vim rabbit hole.

Answer (score 349):

New in Vim 7.3:

> 'colorcolumn' is a comma separated list of screen columns that are 
>   highlighted with ColorColumn.  Useful to align text.  Will 
>   make screen redrawing slower. The screen column can be an absolute number, or 
>   a number preceded with '+' or '-', which is added to or subtracted from 
>   'textwidth'.

Example from the docs:

```
:set colorcolumn=+1        " highlight column after 'textwidth'
:set colorcolumn=+1,+2,+3  " highlight three columns after 'textwidth'
:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
```

You can use absolute numbers as well:

```
:set colorcolumn=80
```

Comment: I think it's good to note here the color is automatically determined by your highlight color unless you manually set it as in the example.

Comment: Note the `highlight` setting must be set _after_ any `colorscheme` commands as that would override your highlight color.

Comment: I went with bright, burn-your-brain-red... 'cause you know... line length

Comment: Do you know of a way to have two different colors for the colorcolumn? I'd like to have two: a plain one at 80 chars for code, and a very faint one at 72 chars for flowing text/comments.

Comment: It would be good to mention that `textwidth` also causes vim to wrap when you are typing.

Comment: @chutsu The Vim color chart is at: http://codeyarns.com/2011/07/29/vim-chart-of-color-names/

Comment: Columns in Vim have one-based indices, so if you want highlight column after max text width using absolute numbers it should be `set colorcolumn=81`

Comment: Then `set colorcolumn=0` to hide it

Answer (score 15):

There is another way to notify about the long line.

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929 <br>
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
```

[Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns)

Answer (score 9):

I use `match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'` which will highlight anything over 80 chars with red.

I put that command in my python.vim and ruby.vim under ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/.

Answer (score 5):

Several answers here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines simple autocommand

```
:au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('Search', '\%<81v.\%>77v', -1)
:au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
```