# Show current <leader> key setting?

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem with VIM whereby none of my  commands work.

Is there a way I can see what my `<leader>` is currently set to?

Comment: The default is usually a backslash.

Comment: @Nick that is not what he is asking.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

To see the current value currently defined for `<leader>`, use:

```
:let mapleader
```

Producing output like:

> mapleader       ,

It may be undefined if not previously set, defaulting instead to a backslash `\`

Comment: Yeah I'm getting `Undefined variable: mapleader`. I'mm make a new question for that though.

Comment: Unless it's not defined yet.  See @Xuan's answer too.

Comment: what means `,`?  is the cmd key ?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa `,` is the leader, which is used as a prefix for other command mappings. See `:help mapleader` -  the default is \

Answer (score 98):

By default `mapleader` is not set, and special string `"<Leader>"` means `\`.

If you do:

```
:echo mapleader
```

you will get

```
Undefined variable: mapleader
Invalid expression: mapleader
```

If you want to set special string `"<Leader>"` to a different key, say `","`, which is recommended by many, do:

```
:let mapleader=","
```

Then

```
:echo mapleader
,
```

Answer (score 21):

Fortunately, `map` expands `<key_name>` values in both the LHS and RHS. You can exploit this to see the value of `<Leader>` even if it is the default value.

```
:nmap temp :echo('your leader is "<Leader>"')<Esc>| execute 'normal temp'| nunmap temp
```

Note that if you put this in your `.vim/vimrc` it will pause with "Press ENTER or type command to continue". Please comment if you know how to fix this.

Comment: or better yet: `:nmap foo :echo('your leader is "<Leader>"')<Esc>| exec 'norm foo'| nun foo`

Comment: @qeatzy how is that better? it looks to be the exact same, except some of the commands (`exec`, `nun`) are abbreviations?