# How to invoke :CtrlSF search key in vim

Tags: vim, plugins

I wondered is there the correct way to  enter search in vim using CtrlSF vim plug-in

I tried click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> nothing work.
I have to really copy paste CtrlSF to vim:

Comment: `ctrlsf.vim` does not come with bindings, despite the name. If you want to bind one, look at `:help nnoremap` and bind something to `<Plug>CtrlSFPrompt`.

Comment: It's not like Mac key mapping. A lot to understand!, Do you have any sample code to insert. Thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @L3viathan let me know that need todo the mapping.
I found [Getting Started With Using Vim](https://kgrz.io/getting-started-with-using-vim.html)
and [Show current  key setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389205/show-current-leader-key-setting)
are good to start.

Here what I did.
Add these code in ~/.vimrc

```
let mapleader=","
nnoremap <leader>W :CtrlSF
```

That's it.

In Vim normal mode type:

```
,W
```

It will type:

```
:CtrlSF
```

Then it work as :CtrlSF suppose to do