# Keep :highlight when using :tabedit in vim

Tags: vim

I use vim. I have a requirement to use 80 or fewer columns. This fix from [Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns) works great:

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
```

The first file I open looks fine. But when I

```
:tabedit some/other/file
```

some/other/file doesn't have the highlight settings and I have to enter them manually. How do I keep the highlighting settings for files I :tabedit?

Comment: Is:
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
in your vrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding those two lines of code to ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim (create if it doesn't exist) does the trick for me.

That's a great snippet, by the way.

ETA: it may be necessary to add this to your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile (pattern) source ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

where `(pattern)` can be something like `/home/foo/bar/**`.

Comment: Thanks! I put those lines in ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim and added

    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile ** source ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim

to my ~/.vimrc