# Is it possible to visualize the right margin in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to make Vim (or gVim, or both) highlight the right margin of the current buffer?

I have just begun to work with Vim for a while, and find it annoying not to have the right margin visible (say, at column 80).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns

Comment: You can define the textwidth and even set nowrap if you want to.

Comment: New in Vim 7.3: `:set cc=81`, or relative to textwidth: `:set cc=+1`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Vim 7.3 introduced colorcolumn.

```
:set colorcolumn=80
```

It may be easier for you to remember the short form.

```
:set cc=80
```

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns for a compatibility improvement.

Comment: @mgold never reference an answer by number. The order changes based on votes. Alway use the share link.

Comment: 5 months later I have Googled for this again and again found the link above to be annoying. Here is the answer he is talking about http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765575/117471 which shows how to make your vimrc compatible with both vim >=7.3 and <7.3

Answer (score 19):

There is no simple way to visualize a vertical edge for the
`textwidth`-margin in Vim 7.2 or earlier; starting with version 7.3,
there is  dedicated `colorcolumn` option. However, one can highlight
all characters beyond the 80-column limit using the `:match` command:

```
:match ErrorMsg /\%>80v.\+/
```

All we need to make it a general solution, is to build the match
pattern on the fly to substitute the correct value of the `textwidth`
option:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * call matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>'.&l:textwidth.'v.\+', -1)
```

Answer (score 7):

I've written a vimscript function in my .vimrc to toggle colorcolumn when I press ,8 (comma followed by 8, where comma is the defined leader for user-defined commands, and eight is my mnemonic key for 'show a margin at the 80th column):

```
" toggle colored right border after 80 chars
set colorcolumn=81
let s:color_column_old = 0

function! s:ToggleColorColumn()
    if s:color_column_old == 0
        let s:color_column_old = &colorcolumn
        windo let &colorcolumn = 0
    else
        windo let &colorcolumn=s:color_column_old
        let s:color_column_old = 0
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>8 :call <SID>ToggleColorColumn()<cr>
```

Comment: Why not a simple one-liner: `:nnoremap <expr> <leader>8 &cc?':let &cc=0<CR>':':let &cc=80<CR>'`

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683696/4694621) of [Jonathan Hartley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10176/) for the older Vim versions like 7.2 as there is no `colorcolumn` in older Vims.

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929

let s:OverLengthToggleVariable=0

function! ToggleOverLength()
        if s:OverLengthToggleVariable == 0
                match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
                let s:OverLengthToggleVariable=1
        else
                match OverLength //
                let s:OverLengthToggleVariable=0
        endif
endfunction

" I like <leader>h since highlight starts with h.                                                                       
nnoremap <leader>h :call ToggleOverLength()<cr>
```