# Showing a different background colour in Vim past 80 characters

Tags: vim

I have seen [Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns), but the answer there highlights only actual content that goes over the 80 character mark. I want to have a 100+ column Vim window open with the leftmost 80 columns using the normal background and anything past that using a slightly different background. The Vim window background should be a different color, not just text that goes over the 80 character point. This would indicate how close I am getting to the 80-char point without having to go over it first.

I don't think this is currently possible, but I thought I'd ask just in case.

Maybe it could be done with a plugin?

### TextMate Example of Desired Vim Right Margin Highlighting

By selecting "Highlight right margin" in TextMate's general preferences, you can see an example of the desired Vim behavior.

[image: TextMate Right Margin Highlighted Example]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns

Answer (score 230):

If you have Vim >= v7.3, you can simply add this to your `.vimrc` to highlight 81 and onward (so 80 is your last valid column):

```
let &colorcolumn=join(range(81,999),",")
```

If you don't see a highlight, you may not have a `ColorColumn` highlight color set. Add this (adjust to suit your preferences):

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27
```

Now I like to highlight column 80 as well as 120 and onward, so I have separate "warning" and "danger" markers. You can do that thusly:

```
let &colorcolumn="80,".join(range(120,999),",")
```

### Example

Here's a screenshot of GVim editing my `.vimrc`.

[image: GVim editing my .vimrc]

*I use Ubuntu Mono 11 font and the [molokai](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) color scheme. You can find my [vim config](https://github.com/justinforce/dotfiles/blob/master/files/nvim/init.vim) and all of my [dotfiles](https://github.com/justinforce/dotfiles) on GitHub.*

Comment: colorcolumn is limited to 256 definitions, per `:help colorcolumn`... in addition, my setting seems to be truncated at some length when using your join technique, although I can't be assed to search through vim's source to figure out what that length is.  Also, vim parses the value of this setting as a string every time it enters a window, initializes a buffer, etc, so this is kind of an expensive way of achieving the desired result.

Comment: I wouldn't call 918 string concatenations expensive. These are computers—they like repetitive tasks. :) If you want to provide the actual bounds, I'd be happy to update my answer. However, I don't think it matters much, so I won't be investigating myself.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, was exactly what I was looking for! Just one more question, is there a way to not set this rules to a specific type of file (.md)?

Comment: @DavidDias Sure! You can do something like `autocmd FileType markdown let &colorcolumn=""` to unset it completely.

Comment: updated link to [vim config](https://github.com/justinforce/dotfiles/blob/master/files/nvim/init.vim)

Comment: @obfk don't touch, if you can avoid it.

Comment: @JustinForce How would you rewrite your solution in "Lua" so that it would work in "Neovim"?

Comment: @71GA I wish I knew! This will still work in Neovim (I use it in Neovim), but I do not know how to script Vim with Lua. Or at all, really. I just cobbled this together from examples over time. Good luck out there! 

Answer (score 82):

Highlight 81 column

```
:set textwidth=80
:set colorcolumn=+1
```

You may also make some styling:

```
:hi ColorColumn guibg=#2d2d2d ctermbg=246
```

Comment: This, and it's also possible to have it highlight up to 256 columns, but unfortunately it takes a list of columns to highlight and there's no shorthand for it, so you would have do to something like `:set colorcolumn=+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6` etcetera possibly all the way up to `+256` for however wide you think you'd like your right margin. This however will only highlight lines which exist in the buffer, not all lines in the window.

Comment: @Dyslexic Tangent: Why not highlight the first 80 columns instead?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Set your background to the color you want to use to highlight >80 columns, and set colorcolumn for all columns from 1-80, and set the highlight group for colorcolumn to be the color you want your normal background to be.

Comment: One question, while I can set the colour properly by typing `:hi colorcolumn ...` it doesn't seem to work when I put it in my .vimrc. Do you know know how to do that?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as robbrit - If I run the highlight command in ex mode, it looks good, but if I have it in my vimrc file, it destroys my colorscheme...

Comment: In vim 7.0 and 7.2, I get “Unknown option: colorcolumn”. It works in vim 7.3.

Answer (score 20):

Solution proposed in comment above. Highlight your background first then highlight the ColorColumn black as an overlay. Set your colorcolumn to lines 1-80.

```
hi Normal guibg=#32322f ctermbg=236
hi NonText guibg=#32322f ctermbg=236
hi ColorColumn guibg=#000000 ctermbg=0
let &colorcolumn=join(range(1,80),",")
```

Comment: This is simple yet brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
:/\%>80v./+
```

it will mark +80 characters as error

Comment: So clever in a pinch. I like it because it adapts to theme changes. Thanks.

Comment: @GoTTimw Too bad that this can't be applied in a configuration file...

Comment: @71GA   match Error /\%81v.\+/
thats for older vim in newer i use 'hi ColorColumn guibg=#000000 ctermbg=233
let &colorcolumn="80,".join(range(120,999),",")' to mark single column 80 and then all columns past 120

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible to have what you want,
but I following this question since I am interested
in such a thing myself.

Maybe, I am stating the obvious, but you could setup
the highligth in the 70th+ columns to get an indication
of how close you get to the 80th column.

Answer (score 0):

For those using onedark.vim like me that wants a solution posted by Conner, I added these lines to my vimrc file

```
let &colorcolumn=join(range(1,80),",")
let g:onedark_color_overrides = {
  \ "black": {"gui": "#2C323C", "cterm": "236", "cterm16": "8"},
  \ "cursor_grey": {"gui": "#282C34", "cterm": "235", "cterm16": "0"}
  \ }
```

I just swapped the two values, took it from the source code of onedark