# Accessing vim settings values in regexp

Tags: vim

Hi I am using a vim setting to highlight columns past the column 80. This hardcoded setting is good enough for programming where I like to keep it in 79 columns. However for LaTeX, plain txt, RST, where I use different `tw` values it is not working for obvious reasons. Is it possible to somehow use the value of `textwidth` setting inside this regexp ? Or if not, how can I approach this problem ?

```
hi OverLength ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

Comment: yeah I think it is a dup

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. You can find some answers to the question you're asking in the body of your post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2447109/329063).

Comment: You could also use ftplugin and set enable the higlihgting only for a certain set of files.

Comment: @romainl I know cc but I prefer this solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just setting the limit, why not have a function with a bind that'll highlight characters past `n` columns?

```
nnoremap <leader>h :call ToggleOverLengthHighlight()<CR>
let g:overlength_enabled = 0
highlight OverLength ctermbg=black guibg=#212121

function! ToggleOverLengthHighlight()
    if g:overlength_enabled == 0
        match OverLength /\%79v.*/
        let g:overlength_enabled = 1
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned on'
    else
        match
        let g:overlength_enabled = 0
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned off'
    endif
endfunction
```

[image]

Comment: in our example, you also have 79 columns hardcoded

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi Eh, "hardcoded" isn't really the right term. Updated my answer. I still think this is a decent solution to this issue, as you won't have to tackle specific filetypes all the time.