# Adding a vertical bar or other marker to tkinter Text widgets at a particular column

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

My intention is to add a vertical bar to IDLE to indicate preferred line length at column 80.

I have tried to find a configuration option for the Text tkinter widget that would allow this but have found nothing.

I was hoping it would be a simple configuration option so I could just add a another item the text_options dictionary within EditorWindow.py found within Python\Lib\idlelib.

I am not sure how styles/themes work but do they have the capability to change the background colour of only 1 column in a Text widget?

Comment: What is a "column bar"? And are you wanting to add it to IDLE or to a program you are writing?

Comment: Text widgets don't have columns, so no, you can't change the background of a column.

Comment: Set column=80 in vim, rulers in vscode. It just indicates preferred line length. I want to extend IDLE so it contains this line/bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447109/showing-a-different-background-colour-in-vim-past-80-characters. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think a better title would be "Adding a vertical bar or other marker to tkinter Text widgets at a particular column".  (You must mean 'column 80', not 'line 80'.)

Comment: Okay thanks, that would clarify what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline of possible solution:

- Create a 1-pixel wide Frame, with a contrasting background color, as a child of the Text.
- Use `.place()` to position the Frame at an appropriate horizontal coordinate.

Possible issues:

- I don't see any easy way to get the coordinate for a particular column.  `Text.bbox("1.80")` looks promising, but doesn't work unless there actually are 80 characters in the line already.  You may have to insert a dummy 80-character line at first, call `update_idletasks` to get the Text to calculate positions, call `bbox` to get the coordinates, then delete the dummy text.  Repeat whenever the display font is changed.
- The line would necessarily appear on top of any text or selection region, which isn't quite the visual appearance I'd expect for a feature like this.