# How to format text, such that single line will not exceed N characters

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I want to know what is the best practice to format selected text, such that each column does not exceed N characters.

For example I had this text at the begging (Note the text doesn't exceed 80 columns):

```
    aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa   
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa                    
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa a aaaaaaaaaaaaaa                
aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa                 
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa
```

And then suddenly I had to change the first line and and text like:

```
BBBBBB BB B BBB BB BBB BBB BBB BBBB BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Such the text will become similar to this:

```
    aaaaaaa aaaaa BBBBBB BB B BBB BB BBB BBB BBB BBBB BBBBBBBBBBBB aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa  
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa                      
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa a aaaaaaaaaaaaaa                 
aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa          
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa
```

So what is the easiest way to format the text to kind force the limit on `columns` up to `80` characters?

#### P.S

I don't wan't to format every line manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_word_wrapping).

Basically, `:set tw=80`, then use the `gq` command to reformat preexisting text. To auto-wrap the entire file, go to the first line and type `gqG` (note capital G).

Comment: Hi @David Norris, I tried what you suggested, it works almost like I want, but not exactly. I would like to keep first paragraphs indented, and that it will affect only text that where selected by `VISUAL`.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033423/vim-command-to-restructure-force-text-to-80-columns).

> Set textwidth to 80, move to the start of the file (can be done with
>   Ctrl-Home or gg), and type gqG.
>
> gqG formats the text starting from the current position and to the end
>   of the file. It will automatically join consecutive lines when
>   possible. You can place a blank line between two lines if you don't
>   want those two to be joined together.