# How do you insert a newline after every 80 characters in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a long line of characters in vim. I'd like to insert a newline after 80 characters. How do I do that?

Comment: This is arguably a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033423/vim-command-to-restructure-force-text-to-80-columns which shows that `set textwidth=80` and `gqq` would do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim command to restructure/force text to 80 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033423/vim-command-to-restructure-force-text-to-80-columns)

Comment: I don't think that `gq` would quite do this; it would do more than what is asked. Specifically, it would rearrange text of lines shorter than 80 characters.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
:%s/.\{80}/&\r/g
```

- %: process the entire file
- s: substitute
- .: matches any character
- {80}: matches every 80 occurrences of previous character (in this case, any character)
- &: the match result
- \r: newline character
- g: perform the replacement globally

Comment: One caveat: if your goal is to wrap lines that are too long, the above command will add the new line character even if the line is exactly 80 character. To avoid this behavior, you need to exclude this case: `:%s/.\{80}\($\)\@!/&\r/g`

Comment: I would be interested in only inserting a line break at the first space occurring after the 80th character.

Comment: Interesting, the "}" doesn't need to be escaped like the other answers (even though the  
  "{" is escaped) ?

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expression:

```
:%s/\(.\{80\}\)/\1\r/g
```

Using recursive Vim macro:

```
qqqqq79la<Enter><esc>@qq@q


qqq  Clear contents in register q.
qq   start marco in register q
79la<Enter> Carriage return after 80 characters.
<esc> go back to normal mode
 @q   run macro q which we are about to create now.
 q   complete recording macro
 @q run macro
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also modify this approved answer to only insert the newline at the first space occurring after the 80th character:

```
%s/\(.\{80\}.\{-}\s\)/\1\r/g
```

Comment: Slightly more readable using the `\v` modifier: `%s/\v(.{80}.{-}\s)/\1\r/g` - I needed something that broke on spaces only, good job :)