# How to break a long line in IdeaVim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I'd like to be able to break lines longer than 100 characters into multiple lines of less than 100 characters in IntelliJ IdeaVim. The Vim solution in [vim command to restructure/force text to 80 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033423/vim-command-to-restructure-force-text-to-80-columns) doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not implemented in IdeaVim yet. Feel free to vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1310 about `:set textwidth` and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-186 about `gq` to re-wrap comments.

Comment: If this matters to you, please vote on those issues! It's 2020 and `gq`/`gw` remains unsupported.

Comment: There is a workaround as posted in the comments of [VIM-186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-186#focus=Comments-27-4355985.0-0) by Tej Chajed:
(reposting gist here for visibility):
Install https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7234-wrap-to-column plugin and map in your .ideavimrc:

`nmap gqq :action com.andrewbrookins.idea.wrap.WrapAction<CR>` and
`vmap gq :action com.andrewbrookins.idea.wrap.WrapAction<CR>`

(see [full comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-186#focus=Comments-27-4355985.0-0) for limitations of workaround.)