# Using shorter textwidth in comments and docstrings

Tags: python, vim, pep8, autocmd

From the mighty [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> [P]lease limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.  For flowing long blocks of text (docstrings or comments), limiting the length to 72 characters is recommended.

When editing Python code in Vim, I set my `textwidth` to 79, and Vim automatically wraps long lines of Python code for me when I hit the character limit. But in comments and docstrings, I need to wrap text at 72 characters instead.

Is there any way to make Vim automatically set `textwidth` to 72 when I'm in a comment or docstring, and set it back when I'm done?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475072/vim-different-textwidth-for-multiline-c-comments

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, I've never done any Vim scripting before, but based on [this question about doing something similar in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475072/vim-different-textwidth-for-multiline-c-comments) and [this tip for checking if you're currently in a comment](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Check_for_comments_independent_of_filetype), I've hacked together a solution.

By default, this uses the PEP8-suggested widths of 79 characters for normal lines and 72 characters for comments, but you can override them by `let`ting `g:python_normal_text_width` or `g:python_comment_text_width` variables, respectively. (Personally, I wrap normal lines at 78 characters.)

Drop this baby in your *.vimrc* and you should be good to go. I may package this up as a plugin later.

```
function! GetPythonTextWidth()
    if !exists('g:python_normal_text_width')
        let normal_text_width = 79
    else
        let normal_text_width = g:python_normal_text_width
    endif

    if !exists('g:python_comment_text_width')
        let comment_text_width = 72
    else
        let comment_text_width = g:python_comment_text_width
    endif

    let cur_syntax = synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 0)), "name")
    if cur_syntax == "Comment"
        return comment_text_width
    elseif cur_syntax == "String"
        " Check to see if we're in a docstring
        let lnum = line(".")
        while lnum >= 1 && (synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(lnum, col([lnum, "$"]) - 1, 0)), "name") == "String" || match(getline(lnum), '\v^\s*$') > -1)
            if match(getline(lnum), "\\('''\\|\"\"\"\\)") > -1
                " Assume that any longstring is a docstring
                return comment_text_width
            endif
            let lnum -= 1
        endwhile
    endif

    return normal_text_width
endfunction

augroup pep8
    au!
    autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * :if &ft == 'python' | :exe 'setlocal textwidth='.GetPythonTextWidth() | :endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Is there any noticeable effect on performance from using the CursorMoved* groups?  I use a similar method, but chose to use the 'InsertEnter' au group rather than CursorMoved*.  CursorMoved is definitely more fine-grained, but 'InsertEnter' was fine-grained enough for me and gets called far less often. Just wanted to mention it as an option, and also to check if you notice any performance issue with 'CursorMoved'.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz I haven't noticed any performance issues using CursorMoved. It makes this script more natural for (e.g.) reformatting existing docstrings, or if, like me, you're new to Vim and still move around a lot while in insert mode. But using InsertEnter will definitely catch the common uses, and use less resources.

Comment: This is awesome; thanks for putting it together. I noticed that in my vim setup, the synIDattr call results in "Constant", not "String", when I'm in a string literal. I had to compare against that as an option in my vimrc.

Comment: Love it.  Any motion towards making this a Vim plugin?

Comment: I have just proposed to add it to the `python-mode` plugin: https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/461

Comment: the issue was closed due to inactivity twice :( ... is there anything us people interested can do to support this getting added to the `python-mode` plugin?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is great! It does not, however, support the habit I have for formatting/editing comments: I make my edits and then use the gqj command, which is essentially, "reformat the current line combined with the next". Then I hit '.' to repeat that for each line (the command itself advances the cursor to the next line). I don't know the vim scripting language very well, so someone may be able to add support for this to the accepted answer. In the meantime, what I have done is map a function key (F6) to change the textwidth to 72, format the line and then change the textwidth back to 79.

```
nmap <F6> :set textwidth=72<CR>gqj:set textwidth=79<CR>
```

Now, when I'm in a docstring, I just make the edit, (ESC) and then hit F6 repeatedly until all the lines are properly formatted.

I added my map command and the accepted answer script to my .vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim.