# Is it possible to have (at the same time) colorcolumns in vim 7.3 with different colors, using the new colorcolumn option?

Tags: vim, syntax

Vim 7.3 has a new option, [colorcolumn](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/options.txt#1528).

I can set a `colorcolumn` color:

```
:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
```

I can have how many colorcolumns I want, but I would like to know if it's possible to have two colorcolumns, each one of them with different colors. Anyone knows if this is possible, or a hack to achieve it using only this new `colorcolumn` feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way. [Fredrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269763/is-it-possible-to-have-at-the-same-time-colorcolumns-in-vim-7-3-with-different/6269963#6269963) is a hack not using `colorcolumn`, but doesn't do exactly what I want.

I did a `:h match` and found the exactly line I need:

```
match OverLength /\%<73v.\%>72v/
```

...and, of course, the colorcolumn.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution makes vim run pretty slow on moderately-sized (100K) files.

Answer (score 6):

Don't think that is possible, but you can sort-of fake it using the proposal in this post [Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns/235970#235970)

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

I.e. use `colorcolumns` but for the one farthest to the right, highlight everything exceeding that using the above.

Comment: This seems to only apply to the rightmost pane, interestingly.