# Highlighting more than 80 characters with a non-standard colorscheme

Tags: vim, coding-style

In vim I am trying to have it highlight my screen when it goes over 80 characters (I am a kernel developer and this is a requirement for kernel code). I am using the following in my .vimrc file to do this

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#59292
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

which was suggested here: [Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns)

However, I am colorblind and as a result I cannot use the default colorscheme and see the text on the screen so I change my default colorscheme using `:colorscheme torte` as well. However, it appears that the colorscheme overrides the highlighting on me (it highlights fine when I don't have the colorscheme specified, and doesn't when it is specified).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work with the `colorscheme` change? Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because most color schemes have this line in their beginning:

```
hi clear
```

This clear all highlighting groups created (you created `OverLength`). This is good, because no colorscheme has every thing set, and colors from the previous scheme used could remain appearing.

To solve, instead of creating a new group, match this pattern as `Error` which is a default Vim group, will be present in every color scheme. Change your two lines by one simply:

```
match Error /\%81v.\+/
```

Comment: @sidyll, The highlighting somehow disappears when creating a split window.

Comment: @vrybas I'm not sure if I understand it. Is it a vertical split? Please consider posting a separate question ;-)

Answer (score 27):

If you have Vim 7.3+ you can use:

```
:set colorcolumn=81
```

Comment: That's really nice, never knew about it. I always created highlight matches, this is way better for working with aligned text. +1, and it will be a matter of preference between this answer and mine. This one is quite easy to set, however only one column gets highlighted (nothing that a `:set cc=80,81,82,83,84,85` doesn't solve :-).

Comment: Yeah... I saw that solution earlier, but I have 7.2 and I am not supposed to upgrade it at work yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sidyll you can also use numbers relative to the 'textwidth'. `set colorcolumn=+1,+2,+3`. See `:h 'cc'` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Colorscheme` event to define OverLength group:

```
augroup AddOverLength
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * :highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#59292
augroup END
```

Note that you must either put all calls to `:colorscheme` that happen in your vimrc after this definition or explicitely launch this event by using `:doautocmd AddOverLength ColorScheme`.