# VIMRC not loading on :tabe

Tags: vim, tabs

I have some various configurations in my `~/.vimrc` that does things like highlight whitespace issues, etc.  When I create a new tab via `:tabe <file_name>`, the subsequent tab loses all of this.  I can `:so $MYVIMRC` to cause it to load but that's obviously not ideal.  Any idea why this is happening or how I can cause it to load when creating new tabs?

Edit: [Here's my .vimrc](http://pastebin.com/GpSp4WK0)

Comment: The functionality you're asking for doesn't make sense: a vimrc file is supposed to be loaded only once per session. If your vimrc does filetype-specific settings for the current buffer, try moving these into a filetype plugin. See `:h ftplugin` and `:h after`.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm just trying to do something like this (filetype agnostic):
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=yellow guibg=yellow  
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/

Comment: Please, post the content of your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Edited in to the original.  Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: Is it problem with highlighting whitespaces and tabs? I have a solution that works also in tabs (and possibility to turn off/on locally for each tab/window). And it should be `syntax match ...` if you want to use that, not only `match ...` I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue I'm struggling with more than anything.  The colors don't seem to load either.  I modified it by prepending "syntax" to the match lines and it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What version of vim? if you can use `matchadd()` I can post a suggestion.

Comment: @JamesB41 Your question is actually very valid. [This popular answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/235970/329063) exhibits exactly the problem you describe: it only works in the file you open first. I guess the solution will be an autocommand or something.

Comment: @244an Currently using 7.0.237

Comment: ok, then you should go for using `match ...` as you already does. Look at the link that @glts wrote. You must do `match` with an autocmd for all mew tabs/windows.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight and strip trailing whitespace, you may be interested in my
[ShowTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966)
and [DeleteTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) plugins, which implement this in a more robust way. (The pages contain links to alternative plugins, too.)