# Turn off vim highlighting for given file type (markdown)

Tags: vim, markdown

I'm using the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235970/49359) in my vimrc to highlight lines over 80 columns.

`highlight OverLength ctermbg=gray ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/`

This works great for code-related files, but it's annoying for me in markdown.  Is there a way to turn off highlighting by file type in my vimrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn off the highlighting for the `markdown` filetype, add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType markdown match none
```

This turns off the `:match` highlighting for that filetype.

(Alternatively, I would recommend putting that into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; this requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

Note that `:match` is *window-local*, so your original code already has issues when working with window splits and switching buffers; this solution inherits this.

Also note that there is `'colorcolumn'` built-in in Vim 7.3+.