# How to avoid vim marking long lines as red when a string exceeds the 73-character column limit

Tags: vim, fortran

I am using `vim` to edit a fortran 90 file. The length of a code line exceeds the 73-character column limit:

```
  print*, &
  "Not sufficiently large neighbours list in dynstillweb, increase max_n"
```

The problem is that vim not only marks as red the exceeding characters (say, `se max_n"`), but also the rest of the code instead of the usual white, yellow, and blue colors which make easier reading the code. Is there any command to insert in the `.vimrc` file to tell vim to increase the character limit and hence avoid the massive red marking?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `let fortran_have_tabs=1`? Otherwise, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns

Comment: Have you set `let fortran_free_source=1`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that vim assumes a fixed source form by default. You need to add the following to your `.vimrc`  :

```
let fortran_free_source=1
```

Here is an excerpt from  `:help fortran.vim`  :

> Fortran code can be in either fixed or free source form.  Note that the
> syntax highlighting will not be correct if the form is incorrectly set.
> When you create a new fortran file, the syntax script assumes fixed source
> form.  If you always use free source form, then
> `:let fortran_free_source=1`
> in your .vimrc prior to the :syntax on command.  If you always use fixed source
> form, then
> `:let fortran_fixed_source=1`
> in your `.vimrc` prior to the `:syntax on` command.