# Match and highlight two sets of columns in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns)  describes how to highlight all characters on a line in VIM past a given line number (80, in this case).

I'd like to have two sets of highlighted characters, columns 81-100 highlighted with one background color, and columns 101+ with another background color.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
" Light highlight characters past column 80.  Red highlight past 100.
highlight OverLength1 ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#5b4f62
match OverLength1 /\%81v.\+/
highlight OverLength2 ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#990500
match OverLength2 /\%101v.\+/
```

as well as this variation on the 3rd line:

```
match OverLength1 /\%81v.\+($|100v)/
```

Neither works.  The best I can get is to match 101+ alone; it seems like the second match overwrites the first match.

I don't like the colorcolumn option, I don't want to highlight empty columns, just text in the ranges specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
" Light highlight characters past column 80.  Red highlight past 100.
highlight OverLength1 ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#5b4f62
match OverLength1 /\%81v.\+/
highlight OverLength2 ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#990500
2match OverLength2 /\%101v.\+/
```

Read more about it on [`:h 2match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%3A2match).