# Run a setting in VIM for specific filetypes only

Tags: vim

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns) where I can highlight code if it exceeds a certain width. However, I don't want that for text files (like LaTeX). Thus, I tried (in my `.vimrc`):

```
if (&ft=='python' || &ft!='r')
    highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#FFD9D9
    match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
endif
```

What am I doing wrong? All code/text is highlighted, even for other types. My LaTeX files are `.Rnw` and thus `set ft` yields `rnoweb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.vimrc` is read only once on startup. So it's a right place to define a highlight (without adding any conditional):

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#FFD9D9
```

But if you want to make a match each time you open a file (with or without a conditional), you have to wrap your `:match` command inside an autocommand (in your `.vimrc`), for example:

```
au BufReadPost * if &ft=='python' || &ft!='r' | match OverLength /\%81v.\+/ | endif
```

Comment: I copied that but still get highlighting every time. Is there any other trap?

Comment: @Xiphias `&ft != 'r'` will match too many things. I think the condition is incorrect. BTW, I'd have gone for a `is_a_text_ft()` function. (Well, [I did actually](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/ft.vim#L53))

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: Ha, shame on me. I just swapped `==` and `!=` but kept `||` instead of `&&`. Now it works :-) Thanks for your reference, but that code is above my vimscript abilities. I'll stick with the above :-)

Comment: @Xiphias, you could still simplify it to `if &ft !~ '\v^$|text|latex|tex|html|docbk|help|mail|man|xhtml|markdown|gitcommit'`

Answer (score 0):

Vim has syntax files for this type of file specific syntax highlighting.

You should create `python.vim` under your `~/.vim/syntax/` directory (on non-windows machines). Then add the following to `python.vim`

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#FFD9D9
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

This way your `vimrc` remains clean and doesn't get cluttered with lot of filetype specific code.

See `:h syn-files` to read more about syntax files.